# What's the difference between quote and quoteInto in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I can't figure out what quoteInto does differently from quote.

Comment: Did you even try searching it via Zend homepage? Everything is described there.

Comment: I did and didn't find it at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`quoteInto()` is for prepping data for an sql query. The `quote()` function only quotes things that may terminate the string literal, such as ', ", \0, etc.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE enabled = ? AND country = ?';
$sql = $users->getAdapter()->quoteInto($sql, 1);
$sql = $users->getAdapter()->quoteInto($sql, 'UK');

//SELECT * FROM users WHERE enabled = 1 AND country = 'UK'

print $db->quote("%some'stuff%") . "\n"; 
// Output: '%some\'stuff%'
```

Comment: shouldn't the 1 be '1' in your output?

Comment: Nope, integars don't need '' only strings

Comment: one more thing, in your second example, who exactly adds that slash to ' , or when does it happen?

Comment: quote() adds the \ to the ' making it safe to put the string in an array or database. without the ' you would get '%some' and then stuff%' without a beginning '

Comment: quoteInto() replaces ALL occurences of the placeholder ('?') at once ! Example above will not work as expected, as it replaces both '?' in first call and resulting SQL will be:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE enabled = 1 AND country = 1` If you want quoteInto() to replace only one placeholder, you have to call it like this: `quoteInto($sql, 'UK', null, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think quoteInto() is the best solution because it only escapes special characters, and applies quotes around it. There is generaly several problem with escaping, for example you must have list of spec. characters for used DBMS and maintain this list - how you know that Zend have this list of your DBMS 100% perfect??
In my opinion there is only one really safe solution -> use parametrized queries.